# google adwords api with google-adwords-api gem

Tags: ruby, google-ads-api

I am trying to access google adwords api with 'google-adwords-api'  ruby gem. 
I have configured as per required. I have also set an test mcc account and api application. But still I am not able to access the api. It is giving following error
`QuotaCheckError.ACCOUNT_INACTIVE`

Also I am trying to set the environment to sandbox which gives following error
`Environment 'SANDBOX' does not support version 'v201306' (AdsCommon::Errors::Error)`

In documentationn it is mentioned that we can access api with test account even before approval.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got fixed this.
The developer token needed for accessing the ad-words api should be created from production account and not from test account.

Comment: Do you know where I can found that option?